# PHP cambiar formato de fecha

Tags: php, mysql, date

Tengo una fecha guardada una BD que tiene el siguiente formato:"04/February/2020". La quiero convertir con strftime() para que quede como "martes 04/febrero/2020" pero me arroja un error de "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in: [ruta del archivo]" y me regresa "Thursday 01 / January / 70".

El codigo queda asi:

```
strftime('%A %d / %B / %y',$cajacompra['fecha producción']);
```

Esta es la consulta que hago para obtener la fecha y otros datos que uso para llenar la tabla:

```
SELECT pcp.id,pcp.numero,pcp.id_proveedor as idproveedor,pcp.costo_pedido as costopedido,pcp.fecha_estimada,CONCAT_WS('',descripcion,' ',CONCAT('(',CONCAT_WS(' x ',CONCAT(frente_es,'cm'),CONCAT(fondo_es,'cm'),CONCAT(altura_es,'cm')),')'),': ',(pry.nombre),', ',pry.codigo) as descripcion,IFNULL(FROM_UNIXTIME(pry.fecha_produccion,'%d/%M/%Y'),'Pendiente') as 'fecha producción' FROM PAT_Caja_Proyecto as pcp,Proyecto as pry WHERE pry.codigo=pcp.codigo_proyecto AND pcp.codigo_proyecto='P-5394' AND pcp.compra='s' ORDER BY id;
```

Y asi es como se ve reflejado en la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el regreso de la Base de Datos es un string.
Puedes intentar lo siguiente.

```
Input: (string) "04/February/2020" //Lo que obtiene la BBDD

setlocale(LC_TIME,"es");                         // Usamos español
$fecha = "04/February/2020";                     // Lo asignamos a una variable
$fecha = str_replace("/", "-", $fecha);          // Cambiamos los / por guiones
$f = strftime('%A %d/%B/%Y', strtotime($fecha)); // Usamos el strftime
echo $f;                                         // Lo mostramos

Output: (string) martes 04/febrero/20
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas pasando un string como segundo argumento, deberias mandar un int.

> strftime ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] ) : string

Prueba con lo siguente. [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime) para convertirlo a una fecha en formato unix.

```
strftime('%A %d / %B / %y', strtotime($cajacompra['fecha producción']));
```

Comment: Me regresa "miércoles 31 / diciembre / 69"

Comment: Que valor te arroja 'fecha produccion', sin usar FROM_UNIXTIME?

Comment: Regresa 1549303200